# How to spy on a method using Vue <script setup> in Cypress

Tags: cypress, vuejs3

It seem that the usual way to spy on methods doesn't work when using script setup syntax sugar. My attempt throws the error:
`TypeError : Attempted to wrap undefined property goToItemUrl as function`

Does anyone know how to achieve this with script setup?

```js
//ExampleComponent.vue
<template>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" @click="goToItemUrl(item.url)">{{ item.title }}</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import {ref} from "vue";
  const item = ref({url:'my/url', title: 'Title'})
  
  const goToItemUrl = (url) => {
    console.log('goToItemUrl', url)
  }
</script>
```

Cypress Test

```js
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent'

describe('ExampleComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.spy(ExampleComponent, 'goToItemUrl').as('goToItemUrl')
    })

    it(`renders the ExampleComponent`, () => {
        cy.mount(ExampleComponent, {})
          .get('.content')
          .should('exist')
          .click()
          .vue()
          .then(() => {
            expect(ExampleComponent.goToItemUrl).to.have.been.calledWith('my/url')
          })
    })
```

Comment: Maybe you need to expose the function https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose

Comment: @Duannx Unfortunatelly defineExpose only exposes data to the template but not on the object itself.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/quickstart#Using-Spies) help? I see that you do it a bit differently than the docs. And in the docs example is given by using vue3 script setup.